# Deriving Equation of Gradient Descent for Polynomial Regression Model

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

I have a polynomial regression model which is called the hypothesis function defined as such :
$$
h( \theta) := \theta_0 + \theta_1 x_1^2 + \theta_2 x_1^3 + \theta_3 x_2^2
$$
We wish to find the gradient descent algorithm for this model,

First of all my main concern is why the hypothesis function is defined as a function of $\theta$ and not $x$. Furthermore my attempted derivation is as such :
\begin{align*}
J(\theta_{0},\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{3})&=\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{argmin}}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\left(h(x_{i})-y_{i}\right)^{2}\\
&=\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{argmin}}\left(\frac{1}{2}(h(x_{1})-y_{1})^{2}+\frac{1}{2}(h(x_{2})-y_{2})^{2}\right)
\end{align*}
I can not proceed without knowing how this hypothesis function is defined because I only know that hypothesis function is a function of $x$ with $\theta$ parameters which is not the case here with the defined hypothesis function